# Use Windows Defender API to scan data without writing it to disk?

Tags: winapi, antivirus, windows-defender

Is it possible to use Windows Defender's Win32 APIs to programmatically scan data in memory without first writing it to disk? The [only options appear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/mpresource-info) to be directories or individual file paths, but it's possible I'm missing something obvious.

A use case would be a file upload API where we do not want the file to hit the disk at all without a scan, or we only save it in encrypted form, or we are saving it only to a database blob, etc.

Ideally there would be an API that accepted a COM `IStream` as an input, so it would support arbitrary streamable data sources.

If there is no way to do this, can anyone point me to where in the Microsoft online community I could make this feature suggestion?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/amsi/antimalware-scan-interface-portal

Comment: @luke Oooh. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/amsi/nf-amsi-amsiscanbuffer. Is this actually what I think it is?

Comment: @luke or better yet this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/amsi/nf-amsi-iantimalwareprovider-scan. Why didn't you just answer? This looks perfect, but I'm almost skeptical it's too good to be true.

Answer (score 1):

According to Luke's suggestion:

You could try to use [IAntimalwareProvider::Scan method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/amsi/nf-amsi-iantimalwareprovider-scan) to scan a stream of content.

Comment: Apparently it is too good to be true - https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/issues/62. 16 MB is an unacceptable limitation. Can you or anyone else confirm if this is accurate?

Comment: Another serious issue I see here is that all the AMSI APIs are synchronous, so they will block the calling thread. I'm not sure this is suitable for a server scenario where many parallel requests could be occurring.

Comment: I agree with Raymond Chen. You could pass a buffer of any size to IAmsiStream::Read.The 16MB limitation is in the platform, not in the sample.